# Customize error message and placement

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

Currently the [Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) plugin automatically add this HTML element to my web page:

```
<span class="validationMessage">This field is required.</span>
```

1. I want to change the "This field is required." text.
2. I want to change the placement of the `<span>` HTML element.
3. I want to add a CSS class (`.err`, specifically) to my textbox so that I can add a red border.

How can that be done with Knockout-Validation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [change the default messages](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Override-Error-Messages) for a validation on a per property basis:

```
test: ko.observable().extend({
        required: {
            params: true,
            message: "This is required"
        }
    })
```

You can use the [`validationMessage` binding](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) to display the errors wherever you want:

```
 <span data-bind="validationMessage: test"></span>
```

And you can use the [`decorateElement` and `errorElementClass` options](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration) (or the [other validation bindings](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings)) to add some custom classes on your inputs:

```
ko.validation.init({
    decorateElement: true,
    errorElementClass: 'err'
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rpq42q6h/).

Comment: This fiddle doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: @leigero yeah, there was a broken link in the fiddle. I've updated it now.